# AquaSec vulnerabilities - cannot exclude library in pom.xml

Tags: java

I'm getting the following AquaSec report

Resource: jackson-databind
Resource: Path: /opt/tomcat/default/webapps/myApp.war:WEB-INF/lib/ehcache-2.10.9.2.jar

Version: 2.11.1
Fix Version: 2.12.6.1

So, there seems like the issue is with jackson-databind version 2.11.1 that came from ehcache-2.10.9.2.jar

However, when I run mvn dependency:tree, I am unable to find jackson-databind 2.11.1.

I do have jackson-databind 2.12.7.1 loaded (see below dependency tree)

```
[INFO] +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.12.7.1:compile
```

I tried excluding jackson-databind from ehcache but no luck (see below)

```
<dependency>
<groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
<artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
<version>2.10.9.2</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded ehcache-2.10.9.2.jar.  Turns out, there is a directory called rest-management-private-classpath.  This is where com.fasterxml.jackson.databind is.

Searching for rest-management-private-classpath, I came to this page which helped fix the problem.

[Ehcache 2 maven dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71931103/ehcache-2-maven-dependency)

Answer at the bottom of the page.